# How does an aggregate function affect the columns queried along with it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables :-

`Movies(movieID,movieTitle,Director)`

and

`Rating(ratingID,movieID,movieRating,ratingDate)`

Now i write the following syntax to be queried on these Tables -

`SELECT movieTitle,max(movieRating) 
 FROM Movie M,Rating R
 WHERE R.movieID = M.movieID 
 GROUPBY R.movieID;`

What i would like to ask is:

Provided that for each subgroup formed by `movieID` i have a unique `max(movieRating)` value i get only one row of `movieTitle` and `max(movieRating)` for each `movieID` sub-group. Shouldn't i be getting many duplicate rows of `movieTitle` and `max(movieRating)` for how many ever times a `movieTitle` entry exists in the Table ?

Let me illustrate my doubt with an example -

Assuming my entries are as follows(I have only included the relevant ones):

```
movieID  movieTitle movieRating
  1      Lost Stars    3
  1      Lost Stars    4
  1      Lost Stars    5
```

When i run the query on these values i get
`Lost Stars    5`
as the answer.That is the row is returned only once as the answer.

Shouldn't i be getting -
`Lost Stars    5`
`Lost Stars    5`
`Lost Stars    5`
as the answer.
That is shouldn't i be getting the value 3 times(for each time a `Lost Stars` entry exists in the table)?

Could you please explain why it works in this fashion?

I am new to SQL and i apologize if this is a very basic doubt. I would really appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY will group records and return distinct values.  In your case, the records all share the same movie title and id.  The only distinct value is the rating, and you're requesting the max, not the actual ratings associated with each record.

Compare your result to the result from:

```
SELECT R.movieTitle,M.movieRating,max(M.movieRating) 
 FROM Movie M,Rating R
 WHERE R.movieID = M.movieID 
 GROUP BY R.movieID, R.movieTitle, M.movieRating;
```

NOTE:  you must group by any field in your select clause that is not an aggregate, so you must group by movieTitle if you're selecting it.

The result from that query will give you all 3 records because it's selecting the movieRating value, which differs on all of the records.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifying my doubt. The NOTE you included really helped me sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping by the `movieID`, which means that you'll get only one row for each `movieID` with all aggregates rolled up to those groups. If those rows had the same `movieTitle`, but some rows had different `movieID` values then you would see multiple rows, but that's a quirk in MySQL. I believe that most RDBMSs will give you an error for trying to return a column that is not in a `GROUP BY` and is not part of an aggregate function.

Comment: . . Actually, the use of `GROUP BY movieID` and `movieTitle` is probably consistent with the ANSI standard, because `movieID` is unique in the table.  Postgres definitely supports the use of declared unique keys in the `GROUP BY` along with other columns from the table.  Other databases may also support this standard functionality in the future.  However, I doubt the OP understands this nuance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to what do you mean by "all aggregates rolled up to those groups"?

Comment: Never mind i understand what you are trying to say, what you are saying is just a different form of the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY partitions the rows one group per subrow value consisting of the grouped columns. Here, movieID. So there is only one such subrow value per group. Aggregates in the SELECT calculate one value by using all the rows of a group, so there's only one value per group. Here, MAX(movieRating). And if a DBMS supports it, you can SELECT on sets of columns that the DBMS can deduce are single-valued per subrow value on the grouped columns per specified deduction rules. One of those rules is if the column set is UNIQUE.

If you want the three rows returned then you should be also grouping on movieTitle.

Prior to Version 5.7.5 MySQL defaulted to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option disabled, so that it did not give an error if you broke those rules. It would return some value from those of the rows of each group for such columns. So if the values were unique (declared or not) your query would return the same value as if uniqueness was deduced. Here, movieTitle.

But as of 5.7.5, deduction works and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY defaults to enabled. So if your uniquness can be deduced, movieTitle is ok in the SELECT, but otherwise you will get an error. You should declare any UNIQUEs you know about in your base tables to support deduction.

From [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual Section 12.20.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)
:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

> See Section 12.20.4, “Detection of Functional Dependence”.